# GPUImage get different result on real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-simulator, gpuimage

I use `GPUImageLookupFilter` for image processing.
It's seem to be okay with Simulator, but when i run my application on real device, i got different result of image.

Here is two image

- [Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLhMI.jpg)
- [Real device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2cBC.png)

Could somebody tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Is this with the latest code from the repository? There was an issue with the use of low precision floats in the fragment shader months ago, but that was fixed. It acted just like this, and seemed to have gone away after that fix.

Comment: No, i've updated latest version of GPUImage

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're getting some saturation in the computation, maybe (to confirm) coming from different computation precision between the simulator and the real device.

In simulator, GPUImage code is executed on the host (development machine) GPU while it os executed on the actual device GPU in the real device. The gap between GPU capacities can be huge, especially if the dev machine is a recent one while the real device is an older one (iPhone 4 for example).